# access the bootstrap-wysihtml5 editor object

Tags: jquery, wysiwyg

I'm trying to acces into an bootstrap-wysihtml5 editor object. I'm doing this by this way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('.someLink').live('click', function () {
          var wysihtml5Editor = $('#textarea').wysihtml5().editor;
          console.log('wysihtml5Editor: '+wysihtml5Editor);
          wysihtml5Editor.composer.commands.exec("bold");
     });
});
```

Chrome console returns:

```
> wysihtml5Editor: undefined
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'composer' of undefined
```

So, the point is.

Which is the way to acces into an wysihtml5 object?

The point of everything is insert some html code into my textarea.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.someLink').live('click', function () {
     $('#textarea').wysihtml5();
     var wysihtml5Editor = $("#textarea").data("wysihtml5").editor;
     console.log('wysihtml5Editor: '+wysihtml5Editor);
     // The following is important since wysihtml5 is initialized asynchronously
     wysihtml5Editor.observe("load", function() {
       wysihtml5Editor.composer.commands.exec("bold");
     });
   });
});
```