# Validation in Bootstrap wysiwyg5 editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, wysihtml5

I am using Bootstrap wysiwyg5 editor as a part of a form.

This text area happens to be a required field(should not be empty). I want to validate if the user has entered any value on to this field or not. I see that Bootstrap wysiwyg uses a Iframe to display the content. I tried to access the content of the iframe's body in jQuery by doing this:

```
$('.textarea.wysihtml5-editor').html()
```

but failed.

My question is: How do I check if the user has entered some text in this Bootstrap wysiwyg `textarea`. Please help me out.

PS: I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092792/access-the-bootstrap-wysihtml5-editor-object) question, but it was not very helpful.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I know the question is old, but maybe help somebody looking for this..

To make the JQuery Validation work with WysiHtml5, just set the plugin to not ignore hidden textareas:

```
$('#form').validate({
   ignore: ":hidden:not(textarea)",     
   rules: {     
       WysiHtmlField: "required"
   },
   submitHandler: function(form) { ... }
});
```

Comment: Saved my lot of time ! Thank you very much

Comment: Wow That's great

Answer (score 2):

you need to listen for the blur event then check the editor.textareaElement of the editor to get the underlying textarea.

```
var editor = new wysihtml5.Editor("wysihtml5-editor");

editor.on('blur', function() {
    if( this.textareaElement.value.length === 0 ) { alert('no blank entries!'); }
});
```

Most of this info is on their wiki: https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5/wiki

Comment: am sorry this does not work! first line is not working :
`var editor = new wysihtml5.Editor("wysihtml5-editor");-`does not work!    where as
`$(".textarea").wysihtml5();`-works

Comment: dude, the core of the sample is what you need. I included the above line to show you that you need to collect the editor object. o_O

Answer (score 1):

you are using **bootstrap-wysihtml5** and rlemon answered you with the code for the regular non bootstrap-themed WYSIHTML5.

your

> var editor = new wysihtml5.Editor("wysihtml5-editor");

code is actually inside bootstrap-wysihtml5-0.0.2.js (or whatever version you used)

however this wrapper defines the editor object as window.editor so you can create your blur function like this , after you initiate you wysihtml5 element.

```
window.editor.on('blur', function() {
 // do whatever you want to do on blur
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution, by jquery we are adding nicehide class to our wysihtml5, now we can validate it, I hide it with visibility hidden, maybe ur code could without it, other solution could be put iframe class and nicehide to same position...

```
jQuery('.wysihtml5').wysihtml5({
"events":      {
"load": function () {
jQuery('.wysihtml5').addClass('nicehide');
}
}
});


.nicehide {
resize: none;
display: block !important;
width: 0;
height: 0;
margin: -200px 0 0 0;
float: left;
visibility:hidden;
}
```

Thanks to https://github.com/jhollingworth/bootstrap-wysihtml5/issues/275 , I only added visibility..

Answer (score 0):

html5 validation (required="required" for example) don't work.
this happens because the original field is hidden.

In case for validation in bootstrap wysiwyg5 editor based on your question, try this:

```
jQuery('.wysihtml5').wysihtml5({
   "events":      {
       "load": function () {
           jQuery('.wysihtml5').addClass('nicehide');
       }
   }
});
```

and it's for the css:

```
.nicehide {
    resize: none;
    display: block !important;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 -15px;
    float: left;
    border: none;
}
```

Hope that helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

For me this code worked. 
HTML

```
<input type='text' name='title' />
<textarea name='content' class="textarea" placeholder="Enter text ..." 
style="width: 100%; height: 200px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px;"></textarea>
<span id='after'></span>
```

CSS

```
.textnothide {
    display: block !important;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

JS

```
<script>
  $('.textarea').wysihtml5(
      events: {
        load: function () {
            $('.textarea').addClass('textnothide');
        }
    }
  );
<script>
```

This code prevents hiding the textarea. But unfortunately error message appears before text area. This can also be prevented.

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).hasClass('error-help-block')) {
        var id = $(e.target).attr('id');
        if (id == 'content-error') {
            $(e.target).insertBefore($('.after'));
        }
    }
});
```

This code **captures the error message created by jquery validation plugin and add it to a different place**. And removed jquery validation code since not needed.